# Why am I finding what looks like phone numbers in my metered connections settings?

Tags: wi-fi, settings

I find these 10-digit numbers in my metered wifi connections panel. The second number I ran a google search on and was informed that the area code does not exist. I dont know if these are phone numbers. The same search also showed that this impossible number was tagged as harmful as well as scammer calls. Can you guys tell me if these "networks" are somthing to be concerned about or normal. After many searches worded many different ways I could not find any information about ten digit numbers in the metered wifi connections setting panel. They do not show up under saved networks so Im stumped here. Thanks for your time.[image: Screenshot of concern]

Comment: Im sorry but it was the first number that I googled not the second. The settings can be found under data usage->network restrictions

Comment: Most likely those Wifi networks are from routers which are pre-configured with a random Wifi network name based on numbers. That one number is a telephone number is most likely just coincidence.

Comment: Yes that would be nice. However, there is no way to delete them since they do not show up under saved networks and I didnt connect to any routers with numbers as SSID.